# how do we get terminate event in DEXT - Problem in Catalina DEXT driver

Tags: macos, operating-system, macos-catalina, iokit, driverkit

I am new to KEXT and DEXT for Mac OS.
Trying to port the KEXT driver to DEXT for development purpose.
my Question is:
When we unplug a USB device, in case of KEXT we recieve kIOMessageServiceIsTerminated via the message() call, which tells us that device is terminated.
In DEXT, i could not see messages() function(or similar function). 
How do we design for such scenarios in DEXT (Eg: how to get terminate event in DEXT)?

Answer (score 0):

The only points where you can detect if your communication with an application is closed or the USB was unplugged, are the `Stop` functions of your device class or user client class.